# Generate XML using Xerces-C++

Tags: c++, xerces, xerces-c

I am attempting to generate XML similar to the below using the [`xerces`](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) libraries. I cannot find a suitable example to follow; can anyone with experience in this area please advise?

```
<ad xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="smaato_ad_v0.9.xsd" modelVersion="0.9">
    <richmediaAd>
        <content>
            <script>yadda...yadda... richmedia content ...yadda</script>
        </content>
        <width>728</width>
        <height>90</height>
        <beacons>
            <beacon>http://mysite.com/beacons/mybeacon1</beacon>
            <beacon>http://mysite.com/beacons/mybeacon2</beacon>
        </beacons>
    </richmediaAd>
 </ad>
```

Comment: Do you have any code that shows where you currently are at?

Comment: i am following the example here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31088/Xerces-for-C-Tutorial-Using-Visual-C, however i am not certain whether it will meet my requirements

Comment: OK, what are your requirements? How is the example failing to meet them? What are you having trouble with? Please edit your question with answers to these questions.

Comment: the requirement is to generate xml with the above constraints, including <ad xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="smaato_ad_v0.9.xsd" modelVersion="0.9"> tag

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace the creation of the document in the code of the Codeproject sample with

```
p_DOMDocument = p_DOMImplementation->createDocument(0, L"ad", 0);
```

to create a document with an ad element as root node.

Access the root element in the document with

```
DOMElement* pRoot = p_DOMDocument->getDocumentElement();
```

Create single elements with calls like:

```
DOMElement* pEle = p_DOMDocument->createElement(L"richmediaAd");
pRoot->appendChild(pEle);
```

Set attributes with calls to

```
pEle->setAttribute(L"modelVersion", L"0.9");
```

Set textual content like this:

```
DOMText* pText = p_DOMDocument->createTextNode(L"yadda...yadda...");
pEle->appendChild(pText);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: One last question, i need to set the attribute to the top level - so xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="smaato_ad_v0.9.xsd" modelVersion="0.9" will be with tag ad rather than richmediaad - is this possible with xerces?